# How to Override this type Url in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to override this type url ?

http://localhost:15536/login/checkoutasguest?returnUrl=%2Fcart

Comment: override this type url means?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by overriding a url?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Routing mechanism. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx